# Reading attribute of a node in XML using itemReader Spring Batch

Tags: java, xml, spring-batch

I have an xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employee siteId="1">
   <name>john</name>
   <age>36</age>
</employee>
```

I'd like to get the value of `siteId` (attribute value) using `itemReader`. I'm able to successfully read `name` and `age` child elements. I don't know how to get the value of `siteId`. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question above and add more detail about how you are currently reading `name` and `age`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can read siteId attribute value by specifying  @XmlAttribute(name = "siteId") in class please find example below

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    private int siteId;
    private String name;
    private int age;


    @XmlAttribute(name = "siteId")
    public int getSiteId() {
        return siteId;
    }

    public void setSiteId(int siteId) {
        this.siteId= siteId;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "age")
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```